# How can i use REST and gRPC in same spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, grpc

I am creating a service that will have gRPC endpoints for inter-service communications
and REST endpoint for the client browser.

what will the pom.xml be for it?

since the gRPC server runs on 9000 and REST runs on 8080, how will this work?

Answer (score 0):

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>your-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- gRPC dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.42.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.42.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.42.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- REST dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
# gRPC server port
grpc.server.port=9000

# REST server port
server.port=8080
```

Comment: how does one application run the server in two ports?
can you please share the maven compiler plugin as well?

if I start the main function will it create the rest application server or rpc application server?

Comment: is it possible in the first place?

Comment: @Kakarot it is - they're hosted on separate ports, so you'll have to provide them with your domain, e.g.: https://example.com:9000 for gRPC.

If you want to have them accessible on domain without a port, but rather: https://example.com/grpc & https://example.com/api - then you need to setup a reverse proxy, like Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *grpc-gateway* to bind them. You would find the link below and regarding your same port issue if you are going to use gRPC in microservice you can use the **grpc-spring-boot-starters**. You will the link to both below:

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway

https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter/

Comment: Please post detailed answer and then references.